# remove substring from filenames in subdirectories in mac

Tags: mac, terminal, batch-rename

I have a backup from windows 8 file history that added timestamp to my files in all subdirectories. as the following
_sites (2014_08_04 20_32_19 UTC).extension

I need to remove the whole substring to be as the following:
_sites.extension

I have hundreds of files with the same problem in different dates.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If the substrings are all the same length, you can use a simple file re-namer to get rid of them by truncation (e.g. Lupas Rename or one of the many you can get from nonags.com).

You might have to add a numeric suffix to the files, though, if many have the same core filename (most re-namers can do that in the same operation).

Eep!  I didn't notice the Mac tag.  Forget what I said about Lupas Rename and nonags.com -- you'll need a Mac equivalent.

Comment: Thank you mark for your fast response, File names are not the same length. I wonder if I can do it using command line in terminal because I have many files in folders in subfolders. Thank you,

Comment: The file names don't have to be the same length, only the unwanted suffixes (which look like they may be).  Most re-namers have options to count from either end, when cropping (e.g. the options in Lupas rename are "Left crop n characters" and "Right crop n characters").  Your example above wants a right-crop of 26 chars.